# How to get latest code of Open Source Project where I have contributed

Tags: git, github, open-source

I have contributed to a Open Source Project in GitHub. There are only one branch `master` and in my Local there is also one branch named `master`. I have contributed about 3-4 times.

 When I write `git pull` it show me `Already Up to Date`. Now the problem is in Open Source there are some changes but I can't get update with them.
Like they have **762** lines of code in `README.md` but I have only **722** lines of code. I have tried,

1. git pull
2. git fetch
3. git reset --hard origin/master
4. git fetch --all
5. git reset --hard HEAD
6. git stash
   git pull
7. git fetch origin
   git status

**Help to me solve this with safe way without loose any data from local.**

Comment: `git fetch && git diff origin/master master && git show --format=%H -s origin/master && git show --format=%H -s master` The last two commands are to compare head commit IDs.

Comment: I get the both are same. But still I have 722 line's of code and they have 762

Comment: The same commit IDs means you have exactly the same file. Did `git diff` produce any difference? Line count difference could be explained by line ending issue, that require further investigation. BTW the repo is open source, you can freely publish its URL for us to check the file.

Comment: `git diff` doesn't return anything. `git status` return **On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.**. <br> I am saying line difference because the open source have some more things update that I don't have or can't get.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not showing updates when you pull, that's probably because you forked the project. The origin you've been pushing and pulling from is the one for your forked version.

If you print out `.git/config`, for your local repository, you can see if this is the case. Just run `cat .git/config` in the root of the repository.

In order to get updates from the project, add their git repo as an upstream:

```
git remote add upstream <git url to their project>
```

Then, fetch changes from that upstream:

```
git fetch upstream
```

You can see what changes they've made via `git diff`:

```
git diff master upstream/master
```

**Question:** How did you contribute your changes to the project?

If you pushed, then it's likely you just pushed to your forked version, not the project yourself.

If you created a pull request that got accepted, then the changes got merged in.

**Does their project have your changes?** This determines how to proceed.